# Access properties of a Test Settings file at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a test project which uses MSTest. And I have a **testsettings** file and have a properties in that file. as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="local" id="77572268-dd99-4f8c-a660-f5c8c1eec977" 
              xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>

  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties >
    <Property name="AAA" value="val1"></Property>
    <Property name="BBB" value="val2"></Property>
  </Properties>
</TestSettings>
```

But how can I access these properties in testsettings file values by name in runtime. How can I do that?

This is what currently I'am trying..

```
   [ClassInitialize]
    public static void TestClassInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        var sad = context.Properties["AAA"].ToString();
    }
```

And it gives following exception

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   TestAutomation.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

*And this is not about the **System.NullReferenceException** and this is about how to access a property in a Test settings file in runtime. So this question is not a duplicate.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava This is not a duplicate, this is a separate scenario

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have not properly configured your .runsettings file.

Follow this link [.runsettings file configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) and configure the "SettingsFile" section properly.

Alternatively you can also try "TestRunParameters" section to get this working.

Comment: I need to add  the property in Test settings file because I'm already using it to specify deployment Items. So can I use both run settings & test settings once. I'm executing this test using command line by passing parameters

Comment: I think you can. You can specify the runsettings which points to your test settings.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accessing the properties is not correct. You need to use runsettings file instead.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but you dont need the ending tag of the property tag, here is an example:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="test" value="testValue"/>
</Properties>
```

Once that is done you can use the same code to access the data:
`context.Properties["AAA"].ToString()`
[image: debug window showing the code above]